# Big space under renderImage in Shiny flexdashboard r

Tags: r, shiny, whitespace, flexdashboard

i am new to R and recently started working on a Shiny App. While I've managed to fix most of the problems in the project, I've been struggling with a menu issue for a while. Specifically, over the two inputs that I want to use I want to plot an image that depends on the first input (selectInput). I do this through a renderImage function, but the problem is that when plotting these images a space is generated that I cannot eliminate. I have tried using renderPlot and renderText, but the problem is not solved or they do not give the desired results. Is there a way to eliminate or reduce this space? I am attaching a simplified version of my code and an image of the problem.

````html
---
title: "TEST"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r paquetes, include=FALSE}
{
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(highcharter)
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(readxl)
library(gridExtra)
library(plotly)
library(ggrepel)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(scales)
library(flexdashboard)
}
```

Sidebar {.sidebar data-width=300}
=====================================

<center>

```{r echo = FALSE}
renderImage({  
    filename <- paste0("images/",input$countryInput,".png")
    list(src = filename, height = 100)
})
```

</center>

```{r input01, echo=FALSE}
selectInput("countryInput", "REGIÓN",
    choices = c("NACIONAL","XV ARICA Y PARINACOTA","I TARAPACÁ","II ANTOFAGASTA",
              "III ATACAMA","IV COQUIMBO","V VALPARAÍSO","XIII METROPOLITANA",
              "VI O´HIGGINS","VII MAULE","XVI ÑUBLE","VIII BÍO BÍO",
              "IX ARAUCANÍA","XIV LOS RÍOS","X LOS LAGOS","XI AYSÉN","XII MAGALLANES"))
```

```{r input02, echo=FALSE}
dateRangeInput("dateInput", "TRIMESTRES",
  language = "es",
  format = "yyyy/mm/dd",
  min = as.Date("2018-01-01"),
  max = as.Date("2020-07-01"),
  start = as.Date("2019-07-01"),
  end = as.Date("2020-07-01"),
  separator = "hasta")
```

Página
====================================

Row
-----------------------------

###
````

[Problem photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syx7Q.png)

This is my first post on the forum, so any help is appreciated and I apologize in case I forgot to add information.

Comment: Welcome to SO! One rule to ask a good question is to minimize your code. For example your bunch of `library` calls can be cleaned :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `imageOutput` to control the height of the `div` containing the image:

```
output[["image"]] <- renderImage({  
    filename <- paste0("images/",input$countryInput,".png")
    list(src = filename, height = 100)
})
imageOutput("image", height = "100px")
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a hyperlink when using renderImage?